# Acumatica: Adding the quick process to the Acumatica app?

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to add the quick process to Acumatica app for sales orders, but when I try to add the container I get this error "**sequence contains no matching elements**".  Am I just using the wrong container?
Here is what I have so far:

```
  update screen SO301000 {
    update container "OrderSummary" {
      add recordAction "QuickProcess" {
        behavior = Void
        redirect = True
        redirectToContainer = "ProcessOrder"
      }
    }
    add container "ProcessOrder" {
      visible = False
      fieldsToShow = 2
      add field "WarehouseID"
      add field "CustomDate"
      attachments {
     }
   } 
}
```

Update it seems that the error happens only when I try to add the field WarehouseID.  When I take it out it starts to work, but I do need the field on the app.

Comment: FYI the error message is generic and means the system encountered an unexpected identifier in the mobile configuration (code from your question) > Am I just using the wrong container? - Yes that's possible. Use menu "Help->Web Service->Service Description" to get the list of all valid container/field names you can use in the mobile configuration.

Comment: I am using the Service Description.  I did however find out that it is only happens when I use WarehouseID.  when I use the 'CustomDate' instead of the 'WarehouseID' it appears. Relpace `add field "WarehouseID"` with `add field "CustomDate"`

Comment: It appears correct based on service description. Maybe changing fieldsToShow = 2 will improve behavior.

Comment: Yea that would help, but still got the same error after fixing it.

Comment: It could be a bug in the product.

Comment: I think you are right

Comment: Wouldn't be the first time regarding mobile. You can open a case on Acumatica portal if you happen to have a developer support plan. If it's a bug in the product it can't be fixed through customization.